# Bootstrap datepicker active option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap datepicker and I want to change the active option to be the custom. Now my active option is the first one, named "Today" and I want to be the last one which is custom date.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you give a code example.

Comment: `I'm using bootstrap datepicker and I want to change the active option to be the custom. Now my active option is the first one, named "Today" and I want to be the last one which is custom date.` - **okay? So what is the problem?**

Comment: I've flagged this to close, OP seems to abandon it. @ProEvilz